# Is there any way to set each word its own color in one cell?

Tags: jspdf, jspdf-autotable

Is there any way to set each word its own color in one cell with jspdf-autotable?

```
doc.autoTable({
    body: rows,
    allSectionHooks: true,
    willDrawCell: function(data) {
        if (data.row.section === 'body') {
            // data.cell.raw – always 2 words
            // data.cell.text = "green word" + "red word"
            ...
        }
    },
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes! Instead of relying on the plugin to draw the text you can draw it yourself using `doc.text()`.

Comment: Is there any example to do that?
Thanks in advice

Comment: I think you can look at examples/examples.js in the repo and espicially the custom styles example.